# Puppeteer Automated PDF Download Fails After Initial Download

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, download, puppeteer

I am utilizing Puppeteer to automate the process of downloading PDF files to a specific directory on my PC. The functionality works as expected during the first download, with the PDF being correctly saved to the specified path `(G:\tulsa_county\_output)`. However, I have encountered an issue where subsequent downloads, performed when the target directory is no longer empty, default to the browser's Downloads folder rather than the path previously set.

Below is the relevant section of my script for reference:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
const { waitForDownload } = require("puppeteer-utilz");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
const stealth = StealthPlugin();
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete("iframe.contentWindow");

// ... other code parts omitted for brevity

if (newNewTab) {
    let pdfUrl = newNewTab.url();

    // Attempt to set download behavior
    await newNewTab._client().send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
        behavior: "allow",
        downloadPath: "G:\\tulsa_county\\_output",
    });

    let pdfID = 'xxsx';

    // Initiate PDF download
    await newNewTab.evaluate((link, downloadedFileName) => {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = link;
        a.download = downloadedFileName;
        a.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        console.log(link, "successfully downloaded!");
    }, pdfUrl, `tulsas_${pdfID}.pdf`);

    // Wait for the download to complete
    await waitForDownload("G:\\tulsa_county\\_output");

    // Close the tab
    await newNewTab.close();
}
```

I would like to understand the cause of this inconsistency and ascertain how to maintain the specified download path for all subsequent downloads using Puppeteer. I am aware that directly interacting with `_client()` is not ideal due to the potential for future API changes; however, my current implementation necessitates this approach as there seems to be no alternative in official documentation.

Insights and suggestions to resolve this behavior would be greatly appreciated, especially if there is an established best practice or an alternative method to control the download path in Puppeteer I may have overlooked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with puppeteer-utilz but are you sure you should start waiting after starting the download? This seems like a race condition. A runnable [mcve] along with a package.json would be useful so it's easier to run the code and see the problem.

Comment: please let me share my current full source code.
https://github.com/flurryunicorn/county-lib-scraper/tree/main/tulsa_county
I guess, this will help you to understand about the project